# Chrome, YouTube, Whatsapp keeps crashing

Tags: 7.0-nougat

My phone is 5 years old, Moto G4 play. Updated to Android 7.

Not many apps, still app keeps crashing and I have no idea how to solve, also memory usage of each app is bloated. In app settings page I see Carrier Service is reported as 500MB then I go to Carrier Service settings page, it is recalibrated to 30MB. Then Google authenticator - MFA app shows 250 MB, again I open its settings, gets recalibrated to 16MB. Finally I restarted the phone, now this is stable, but I'm too scared to open many apps simultaneously

Am I seeing hardware failure or Virus. I just installed AVG free version and scanned, it says nothing suspicious is found. I'm worried about both, at least if it is only hardware failure I can start doing routine back-ups

Comment: Virus scanner on Android are regular apps and thus they can not access on most devices about 50% of the data only. Therefore virus scanner on Android are next to useless and what the report, too.

Comment: @Robert that broke my heart. After restart things are stable it seems